# pd.duplicated() groups of duplicates

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have a big dataframe with many columns and rows which results from many Excel files. I'd like to find the files which result in duplicates, since sometimes files partially include observations which should not be in the Excel file.
I know that df[df.duplicated(subset=['A','B'],keep=False)] gives me all the duplicate rows.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3],'B':['Q','Q','R','R','R','P','L','L'],'origin':['file1','file2','file3','file4','file5','file6','file7','file8']})
```

I want the result to look like

```
result = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,2,2,2,3,3],'B':['Q','Q','R','R','R','L','L'],'origin':['file1','file2','file3','file4','file5','file7','file8'],'group':['g1','g1','g2','g2','g2','g3','g3'],'duplicate_count':[2,2,3,3,3,2,2]})
```

However, I'd like to always group the two (or more) corresponding duplicates to then print the corresponding files and the amount of times the duplicate occurs. I was not successful finding the answer.

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: I think some 10 rows with few groups should help explain better what rows have to be removed. Thanks.

Comment: @jezrael thanks for your feedback! I've edited the code lines

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with `keep='False'` for filter all dupes by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), then [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), for numbers per groups use [`ngroup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html), for count [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
cols = ['A','B']
df1 = df[df.duplicated(subset=cols,keep=False)].copy()
df1 = df1.sort_values(cols)
df1['group'] = 'g' + (df1.groupby(cols).ngroup() + 1).astype(str)
df1['duplicate_count'] = df1.groupby(cols)['origin'].transform('size')
print (df1)
   A  B origin group  duplicate_count
0  1  Q  file1    g1                2
1  1  Q  file2    g1                2
2  2  R  file3    g2                3
3  2  R  file4    g2                3
4  2  R  file5    g2                3
6  3  L  file7    g3                2
7  3  L  file8    g3                2
```

Comment: After some testing I managed to do this with a single `groupby` + `apply` + `itertools.count`, but I'm sure grouping twice is faster than applying a custom function.

Comment: Thanks! While it works great for the example, I get Problems with `df1['group'] = 'g' + (df1.groupby(cols).ngroup() + 1).astype(str)` and 
`df1['duplicate_count'] = df1.groupby(cols)['origin'].transform('size')` in my actual dataframe. The first results in "g1" for all rows and the latter throws the error "ValueError: Length of passed values is 7634, index implies 0". Any idea why that might be?

Comment: @monart - What problems? Can you explain more?